# how to pass data to pig relations

Tags: hadoop

Please let me know if we can load a particular field of relation into another as shown below

```
usergroup = GROUP input BY user;

output = FOREACH usergroup {
                intermediate = input.traid;
                distinctdata = DISTINCT intermediate;

        GENERATE group as user,count(distinctdata); };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't load a particular field of relation into another.

Per my understanding you want to distinct values for `input.traid` and then count it.

Here you would always get `1` for `count(distinctdata)` for every user. Why would you want this as output?

`DISTINCT` does not work on specific columns (fields), but is used for tuples (row).

It removes duplicate tuples.